# inserting a value every other letter in a string -python

Tags: python

Having some issues trying to solve this.
The goal is to insert a value n in every other letter in the provided string a.

```py
def insert(a,n):
    k = n
    P = 1
    res = list(''.join(i + k * (P%1==0)
    for P, i in enumerate(a)))
    return str(res)
insert('My name is Pamela', 'x')
```

the return that I'm getting looks like this

```
['M', 'x', 'y', 'x', ' ', 'x', 'n', 'x', 'a', 'x', 'm', 'x', 'e', 'x', ' ', 'x', 'i', 'x', 's', 'x', ' ', 'x', 'P', 'x', 'a', 'x', 'm', 'x', 'e', 'x', 'l', 'x', 'a', 'x']
```

How can I make this come as one string instead of different strings?

Comment: Why do you create a list from the output of `join`, which is a string? I would recommend looking at a basic tutorial or through your learning material, you use many functions and structure in a way that suggest that you don't master their use and purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `''.join`:

```
def insert(a, n):
    return ''.join(l + n for l in a)

print(insert('My name is Pamela', 'x'))
```

Output:

```
Mxyx xnxaxmxex xixsx xPxaxmxexlxax
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler way solution:

```
def insert(a, n):
    res = ''.join(x + y for x, y in zip(a, n * len(a)))
    return res
print(insert('My name is Pamela', 'x'))
```

Result:

```
Mxyx xnxaxmxex xixsx xPxaxmxexlxax
```

`n * len(a)` creates the string `nnnn...` with the same length as `a` & `zip` turns the two strings into pairs of one character from each string. Then `join` turns that into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
fin = ""
return fin.join(res)
```

This should combine the string.

Returns:

```
Mxyx xnxaxmxex xixsx xPxaxmxexlxax
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to insert `'x'` between each 2 letters in `a`, but not at the very end, then this is what you want to write :

```
def insert(a, n):
    return n.join(a)

print(insert('My name is Pamela', 'x')) 
#Mxyx xnxaxmxex xixsx xPxaxmxexlxa
```